# Specflow: Invalid binding: Abstract binding types can have only static binding methods

Tags: specflow

We have step definitions grouped into abstract base classes.

However I've noticed the following warnings:

> Invalid binding: Abstract binding types can have only static binding
>   methods

As far as I can tell this warning is created in [BindingSourceProcessor.cs](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Runtime/Bindings/Discovery/BindingSourceProcessor.cs#L236)

The tests appear to be working correctly, is this something to be concerned by? What is the purpose of this warning?

Comment: Slight aside, but what is the purpose for having abstract classes for your step bindings? What benefit does this give you?

Comment: Good question, we're using abstract base classes to organise step bindings that are used within a group of features and pull in the ScenarioContext. And then a given feature file has a single tag and it's specific steps are in one file and inherit the common steps. The bound class also inherits from base classes that setup the common mvc controller bits and moq bits.

Comment: @AlexKay see my answer.  There may be a good reason to use inheritance, but from your description it might be better to move the setup of mvc controller and moq into a specific setup class which is called from the `[BeforeScenario]` tagged method (which cxan be in its own, non inherited class, and will still get called). The common steps can still be in their own `[Binding]` class and specific steps can again be in their own specific steps class. specflow will find all the steps even if there is no inheritance.

Comment: Thanks Sam good point on using BeforeScenario, we're using BeforeScenario and each 'layer' of the hierarchy each one doing it's corresponding setup. Do you know if their are consequences of using abstract classes / inheritance? As it looks like a relatively recent addition e.g. 'Go To Declaration' doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure of the consequence of using abstract classes/inheritance.  If I was you I would test what happens if I have multiple `[BeforeScenario]` methods in different, non-inherited, step definition classes. Do they all get called? If they do then you might be able to do away with the inheritance completely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not answer your question directly, but I would question the benefit of having  abstract step binding classes.

[Specflow step bindings are global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358108/97614) (unless you specifically [do something to make them non global](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings) - but see the warnings on that page).  Specflow will scan all classes looking for those attributed with the `[Binding]` attribute and will try and match step definitions in the feature files with the attributed step methods in the binding classes.

As a consequence abstract classes which contain step definitions make less sense as step definitions are shared, regardless of whether they are inherited through class inheritance or not.

If you are using abstract classes to access fields so that you can share state between steps then you can use Specflows [ScenarioContext](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext) dictionary or, better (IMHO), use the [context injection feature](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/) to ensure that a shared context is injected into the step definition classes to share state between steps, even if these steps are defined in different classes.

Comment: Thanks Sam, good tips. We're using a mixture of what you mentioned I suppose, with inheritance to keep things organised in c#.

Comment: In our case, we don't use global step bindings but we use tags to scope the steps. If we want to reuse a step between two feature files that are closely related, then we pull the step up into a common ancestor, especially for precondition steps. I think that this scenario should be supported, basically Specflow shouldn't complain about the abstract class as long as there is at least one class that implements it...

Comment: @kkara I'm not sure what you mean by 'we don't use global step bindings'. **All** step bindings in specflow are global, that is the way it works. Putting steps in a common base class is, IMHO, unecessary. You would be able to call your steps from both feature files regardless of which file the steps are in. And you can share state between steps in different classes using the ScenarioContext.Current or by injecting your own custom Context object into each step file.

Comment: We're specifically using [Scope(Tag = "FeatureFileTag")] to make them not be global. There are various reasons behind this decision, one of them being keeping the language separate for each feature file that we write for those steps that we need it to be separate. For steps that are indeed global we use ScenarioContext and global steps.

Comment: @kkara, thanks for the update. Its enlightening to see others use of the framework. Much appreciated. I've updated the answer to include this additional information